# An object to give another object, not only a reference to it

Tags: actionscript-3, object, reference

I'm sorry, I'm sure there are many answers to my question in Internet, but I do not know enough programming to be specific in my search.

Okay, so this is my question. Let's have a look at this example, which is really simple:

```
var obj:Object = new Object;
var bit:Bitmap = new Bitmap;
    obj["key"] = bit;
    obj["key"].x = 30;
    trace(obj["key"].x); //30.

var bit2:Bitmap;
    bit2 = obj["key"];
    trace (bit2.x); //30.
    bit2.x = 60;
    trace(bit2.x) //60.
    trace(obj["key"].x); //60 ???
```

All I'm trying to do is stock a bitmap in an object. And this part is fine

```
trace(obj["key"]); // [Object Bitmap]
```

But, if I try to give this to another object, the way it occurs does not make sense to me. It's like my object gives the reference in memory for the Bitmap and not the bitmap itself. So it seems like I have two references to my bitmap. All of my application is based upon those objects, and I really need a way two obtain a copy of my bitmap and not only a reference to it. So I want to change these properties without have to change them in my object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
private function bmpCopy(srcBmp:Bitmap):Bitmap{
  return new Bitmap(srcBmp.bitmapData.clone());
}

//in your code somewhere...
bit2 = bmpCopy(bit1);
```

You just have remember to free both bitmaps when you are done using them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed it's working. Even tough, I still don't really understand. But that's great, I thought I used it a wrong way.

Comment: The only time you get a new Object of any kind is when you call 'new'. When you assign the value of the object you create to another variable, you don't actually create a new one. The bmpCopy method calls new for you, and srcBmp.bitmapData.clone() is where the actual data is being copied and then passed into the Bitmap constructor. Now you have two Bitmaps with the same pixel data.